# Как вывести элементы списка через пробел в питоне

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть список

```
a = list(map(int, input().split()))
```

При выводе даёт список с элементами через запятую.

К примеру пользователь ввёл:

```
1 2 3 4
```

Программа вывела:

> ```
> 1, 2, 3, 4
> ```

Как убрать запятые и оставить пробелы?

Answer (score 7):

Зачем разбить вводимую строку на части и конвертировать на числа, а затем для вывода *сделать всё снова в обратном порядке?*

Для вашей задачи вам этого *не нужно* (в случае необходимости вы можете сделать это позже):

```
a = input()
print(a)
```

Или вы можете *только разбить ввод в части* (без конвертирования - это можно сделать позже), чтобы дать затем выводу единообразный взгляд:

```
a = input().split()
```

Теперь `a` список и вы хотите соединить его элементы в строку, причём отделить их один от другого *одним пробелом* - используйте стандартный метод `join()` на строку с одним пробелом:

```
b = " ".join(а)
print(b)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
a = list(map(int, input().split()))
print(*a)
```

Answer (score 3):

Вы можете использовать распаковку списка:

```
a = list(map(int, input().split()))
print(*a)
```

По умолчанию разделителем является пробел, но если нужен другой разделитель, то можно использовать параметр sep, например:

```
print(*a, sep='-')
```

выведет на экран:

> 1-2-3-4.

Answer (score 0):

https://ideone.com/X5cYev

```
print(" ".join(map(str, list(map(int, input().split())))))
```

Comment: Зачем приводить к целому, а потом опять к строке?

Comment: @mkkik, потому что в вопросе говорится про список чисел. Пожалуй, стоило разделить на 2 команды - считывание списка и вывод, чтобы подобных вопросов не возникало :)

Comment: @user207200 что убедиться что числа в строке и они целые